# No Audio Playback in VSCode (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, audio, playback

got a strange problem. Suddenly i don't have Audio Playback through VSCode anymore.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

file_path = "C:/Test.mp3"

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file_path)

sound.play()

while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.wait(100)
```

This is the test code.
The File is at the correct location.
If i run the script through VSCode (even with the option "Run Python File in Dedicated Terminal") i don't hear any Audio.

If i convert the script with auto-py-to-exe to an .exe File it works and i hear the Audio.

What could cause this strange behaviour?

I did reinstall VSCode already, run it as an Administrator and checked my Soundmixer, there is nothing muted.

Comment: Can you try to use `pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path) pygame.mixer.music.play()` to load the MP3 file instead of `sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file_path)`?

Comment: what if you run the program (not as an exe, but as a script under a python interpreter) in a terminal outside of VS Code?